# Mann-Kendall test with R

Tags: raster, r

I am trying to do [Mann-Kendall test](https://www.statisticshowto.datasciencecentral.com/mann-kendall-trend-test/) over a stack of 620 MODIS images. The code is as follows:

```
library(sp)
library(raster)
library(Kendall)
library(spatialEco)

setwd("C:\\NDVI_prueba")
rlist=list.files(pattern=".tif$", full.names=T)
rasters=stack(rlist)
rasters

fun_kendall <- function(x){ return(unlist(MannKendall(x)))}
kendall_result <- calc(rasters,fun_kendall)
writeRaster(kendall_result$tau, filename = "C:\\NDVI_prueba\\NDVI_STACK_tau.tif", format="GTiff", overwrite=TRUE)
writeRaster(kendall_result$sl, filename = "C:\\NDVI_prueba\\NDVI_STACK_p-value.tif", format="GTiff", overwrite=TRUE)
```

I cannot make it for 620 images but if I add a stack of 5 images I can make it. Does anyone know why?

Comment: Why not run the spatialEco::raster.kendall function?

Comment: logo.trend <- raster.kendall(rasters, p.value=TRUE, confidence=TRUE)
   names(logo.trend) <- c("slope","p.value","LCI","UCI")
     plot(logo.trend)

How can I download as a (.tif) just the "p_value" result to visualise it in ArcMap?

Comment: Where's it going wrong? I can do it for 620 images in a stack of rasters that are 6x4. Maybe your rasters are too big? Are you getting error messages? Or is it just taking a long time?

Comment: @JRichardson, have you read the function help? Why are you assigning names? The rasters are already named besides, you are missing the tau raster, which represent the temporal correlations. To subset a stack and write raster just use a double bracket with the function to write a raster, it will recognize the file extension -  raster::writeRaster(x[["p.value"]], "pvalue.tif")

Answer (score 2):

This works for me, running the test on 620 layers, but they are only 6x4 cells in size:

```
> rlist = lapply(1:620, function(i){raster(matrix(runif(24),6,4))})
> rasters = stack(rlist)
> kendall_result <- calc(rasters,fun_kendall)
> plot(kendall_result)
```

Now we have your error message we can track this down. `IFAULT = 12`.

In the source code, the R calls FORTRAN and checks `ier` on return:

```
if (ier != 0) {
    cat(paste("WARNING: Error exit, tauk2. IFAULT = ", ier), 
        fill = TRUE)
}
```

Looking at the FORTRAN code:

```
C THIS ONLY HAPPENS WHEN N<4. aim. 06/07/2009
IER = 12
```

So I can get your error if I try an M-K test with three values:

```
> MannKendall(c(1,2,3))
WARNING: Error exit, tauk2. IFAULT =  12
tau = 1, 2-sided pvalue =1
```

But you've got 620? So what's going wrong? Maybe 617 of them are NA, and you are left with 3 values:

```
> MannKendall(c(1,2,3,NA,NA))
WARNING: Error exit, tauk2. IFAULT =  12
tau = 1, 2-sided pvalue =1
```

I think you need to trap this problem in your `fun_kendall` function and return something else if there's not enough non-NA values to run the test.

You can check my hypothesis by finding out if there are pixels where only 3 or fewer values are not NA.

Comment: It gives me the following error after 5h processing:

WARNING: Error exit, tauk2. IFAULT = 12

Comment: *VERY* useful. I reckon you've got NAs. See update.

Comment: Yes, depending on the image there are different number of NA values in different cells. As far as I understand, most of the cells will have NA at some observation. Can I change those NA to some value that R understands that it is NoData?

Comment: `NA` *means* `NoData`. Your problem is getting your function to work on small data sets where the test statistic probably degenerates. If you have only one or two points, how can you test for a monotonic trend? You need to catch this and return some NA values to fill the return value rasters with...

Comment: @JRichardson It is critical that you follow standard temporal modeling practices in analyzing your data. Just because it is a raster stack and you can throw functions at it does not mean that you can ignore assumptions and common data practices. You should fill missing data in the time-series and very likely smooth the data using something like a Savitzky-Golay filter. For this statistic, you should not have NA's in your data.